# Removing TAG URLs from Joomla Search Results

Tags: php, html, joomla, joomla3.0

Let's imagine that we tag a Joomla article named **"My Article One"** with the tag word **"hello"**

If we go inside the Joomla search bar and look for the keyword **"hello"** Joomla will give these results.

**RESULTS**

**1. hello**

**2. My Article One**

Joomla is displaying both the new tag URL created together with the article that has the tag.

**Is there a way to eliminate all the TAG URLs on results?**

Like just showing the articles with those tags. Like below

**RESULTS**

**1. My Article One**

To see a real example of the problem go here: https://highsierracamp.com/

And inside the search bar type "map" which is a tag.

The results will display 6 items.

Results 1, 2 and 3 are tag components and I don't want them.

I only want the articles which are results 4, 5 and 6.

I tried disabling the search plugins but this doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like there are very many ways to control how search results are displayed whether in the component options, the menu options or the module options.

Looking at the source code of search results, there do not seem to be any distinguishing CSS selectors to be able to hide the tag results using custom CSS.

The only way I can see that this could be done is to create a template override. There is an example of how to do this at: https://www.joomshaper.com/blog/how-to-improve-search-results-page-in-joomla-3-4

Comment: Yeah I already tried template override but there is not way at the moment to just wrap tags only with CSS as results does not separates articles from tag components. I will need to research further this. Thanks